# How can i switch between 2 different 2 different browsers in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, automation

I want to verify a new message is received and scrolled up automatically for another user. So I opened a message chat window for 2 different user's account in different browsers (Mozilla & Chrome). I sent a text message from User1(Chrome). Now, how can I verify that new message is received and scrolled up automatically for the User2(Firefox)?

Comment: You make two drivers... 1): chromedriver, 2): geckodriver...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I understand that you already achieved for setting up two different drivers for your tests as following sentence of you :  *So i openned message chat window for 2 different user's account in different browsers (Mozilla & Chrome)*

Now you can wait explicitly for that chat message after sending it to another user with `WebDriverWait` as following code :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(
ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(locater)));
```

Before that wait, you can get current location of past message and and you can also validate it after scrolling up with following method :

```
WebElement Image = driver.findElement(By.xpath(locater));
Point elementLocation = Image.getLocation();
int xCordinates = elementLocation.getX();
int yCordinates = elementLocation.getY();
```

For two different browsers, you should init 2 different `WebDriver` as following :

```
 WebDriver driver = New ChromeDriver();
 WebDriver driver2 = New FirefoxDriver();
```

Comment: But how i can focus on another browser to verify new received chat message and scrolling?